# Beginner to C#: How to do constructor chaining, overriding and using :this / :base?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, overloading, chaining

I've studied Java last year and I don't think I ever had issues with writing constructors. I'm unfortunately so confused at how overloading and chaining in C# works, or even the basic concept of it.

I've seen :base get used in inheritence, but I'm not sure how.
I've seen :this get used in many places, and it always boggles me why it's used.

Here's an example of some code with :this (made public variables without setters/getters for sake of argument).

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string height;
    public int age;
    public string colour;

public Person():this("George", "Seville", "45cm", 10, "Black")
    {
    // This is the default constructor, and we're defining the default 
values.
     }

public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string height, int age, 
string colour)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

}}
```

I can only understand how the first constructor is being used e.g. making a simple object of "Person" would give it the default values. That's as far as I can understand. This code is unfinished since it shows 2 default constructors. I'd like to be able to overload and chain for every variant available i.e. 1 parameter, 2 parameter... so they all overload and chain appropriately.

So it should kind of (might not be right) look like this:

```
public Person():this("George", "Seville", "45cm", 10, "Black")
    {
    // This is the default constructor, and we're defining the default 
values.
     }

public Person(string firstName):this(firstName, "George", "Seville", "45cm", 
10, Black)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

public Person(string firstName, string lastName):this(firstName, lastName, 
"Seville", "45cm", 10, Black)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

Of course I'm not sure if any of the code above makes sense, but I've seen some Classes with constructors with :this for each of them, and each constructor links to the one below it until the user can create an Object with any combination of parameters defined.

As for :base, this completely confuses me. Here's an example I've actually found online:

```
    public class Circle:Shape
{
    public Circle():this(Color.Black, new Point(0,0), 1)
    {
    }

    public Circle(Color Colour, Point Position, double Radius):base(Colour, 
Position) 
    {
        this.Radius = Radius;
    }
```

I think :base refers to the parent class, but I'm not sure why and how. Also, why is :this being used in the first constructor and not :base?

There are the 2 aspects I'm very confused with. Using :this and :base and understanding exactly how constructor chaining and overloading works. Please let me know if my question is too abstract. I've tried to be as specific as possible.

Thank you all so much for your support and time. Much appreciated!

Comment: In the last one, calling `this` calls the constructor in Circle then that constructor calls the base constructor in Shape that takes Color and Position.

Comment: You can give parameters default values and as such will not NEED to be supplied. that way you can just write 1 constructor with a bunch of optional parameters.

Comment: `this` keyword is used when you want to call constructor of same class while `base` keyword is used when you want to call constructor of base class or parent class. In your last example, your default constructor is calling overloaded constructor of `Circle` class and overloaded constructor is calling parameterized constructor of `Shape` class. Further more, `base` keyword can also be used when you want to call any method of base class or parent class.

Comment: If you know and feel comfortable with Java, maybe this is relevant for you: [Inheritance and Derived Classes (C# vs Java)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228387.aspx) which has a special focus on the similarities and differences between C# and Java when it comes to inheritance and derived classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to explain it as simple as I can.

### Constructor overloading

Nothing new here, it's just like overloading any other method - You simply need the same name but a different signature (meaning different parameters passing into the constructor).

### Constructor chaining

This is done by using the keyword `this` - just like in the code samples in your question.
btw, I usually use it to go from the most elaborate constructor to the simplest one.
sample code:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Children = new List<Person>();
    }

    public Person(string firstName)
        : this()
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
        : this(firstName)
    {
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> Children { get; }
}
```

Of course, setting default values to properties by using constructor chaining is a valid design and I've used it myself when I needed it, but that's usually not the case.

### The keyword `base`

This keyword always refers to the base (or parent) class. 
You will see it a lot when overriding methods and properties as well.
When it comes to constructors - your assumption is correct - it does refer to the base (or parent) class.
So when used in a constructor (like in your Circle example), you can control what overload of the base constructors your derived (or child) class constructor will execute.
So, for instance, if your base class contains three constructors, you can choose which one of them you want to call.

c# will chain constructors of derived class to the default constructor of the base class unless specified otherwise.
Please note that if you inherit from a class that has no default (meaning: parameterless) constructor you must specify the `: base(...)` in your constructors, even if there is only one constructor to your base class (since that's the only way you can pass the needed parameters to it).

Comment: Thank you! I think my confusion originated from the use of ":this". In Java I never really wanted to set default values since all my objects were intended for initialisation with parameters filled in.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking `: this(...)` refers to a constructor of the current class. As in your example this can be used to avoid code duplication. I think the example given does not make too much sense, from a logical perspective, but it's legal C# and - basically - how `: this(...)` is used

The second example is a mit more logical - or coherent, as the default constructor provides sensible default values to pass to the parametrized constructor.

This is the default constructor, which creates sensible defaults for the values to pass to the parametrized constructor:

```
public Circle():this(Color.Black, new Point(0,0), 1)
```

This is the parametrized constructor it passes the parameters that are also needed by the base class to the constructor of Shape:

```
public Circle(Color Colour, Point Position, double Radius):base(Colour, Position)
```

If you need a standard circle you can create one with

```
var shape = new Circle();
```

If you on the other hand, need a circle at a specific position, with a specific color and a specific radius, you can create one with the parametrized constructor

```
var shape = new Circle(Color.Silver, new Point(1,2), 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think :base refers to the parent class, but I'm not sure why and how

`base` is a keyword to access members of the parent class.

1) `var p = base.Property;` will access a field or property from the parent class

2) `base.Method();` will access a method from the parent class

3) `base(..)` will access a constructor from the parent class

> why is :this being used in the first constructor and not :base?

`this` is the keyword to access memebers of the very same class. There are 3 parameters which define the properties of a `Circle`. `Circle` and `Shape` share only 1 property: `color`. So the default constructor calls the more specialized constructor of the same class `Circle` (that's why `this()`) and the second constructor passes the shared property `color` to the parent to be dealt with.

```
public class Circle:Shape
{
    public Circle():this(Color.Black, new Point(0,0), 1)
    {
    }

    public Circle(Color Colour, Point Position, double Radius):base(Colour, 
Position) 
    {
        this.Radius = Radius;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, "base" refers to Shape(Color Colour, Point Position), "this" refers to Circle(Color Colour, Point Position, double Radius).

Answer (score 0):

The first constructor is accessing the second one in the definition, which is why it is using :this.

The second constructor is using the constructor defined in the base class, which is why it is using base:

If you create an instance of Circle using:

```
Circle()
```

It would use the first constructor, which would call the second constructor (adding the parameters it requires), which would call the constructor in the base class.